# PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer for case insensitive matching

Tags: java, spring-batch

In my spring batch project I am using PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer to match the pattern of fixed length file.

```
HashMap<String, LineTokenizer> matchers = new HashMap<>();
matchers.put("ABC*", abcRecordTokenizer());
matchers.put("wxyz*", wxyzRecoredTokenizer());
```

I have the requirement where we need to match case insensitive records. for ex. `abc`, `Abc`, `Wxyz`  etc

is there any way so that we cam achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The `PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer` uses a [PatternMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/support/PatternMatcher.html) which does not seem to support what you are looking for (it is in turn lifted from Spring's `AntPatternMatcher`).

You have two options:

- Extend the `PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer` and override `tokenize` as needed
- Create a custom `LineTokenizer`

Comment: Hi @Mahmoud Ben Hassine, Hvae you any example how to extend the PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer and override tokenize ?

Comment: No unfortunately, but it should be like extending a regular Java class and overriding a method.